# SVN partial mirror

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mirror

Is there anyway, either with SVN or git-svn, to clone a subset of revisions of a repository that I have read-only access to? For example, I would like to have an offline cache of a gigantic repository that currently is on revision 200000, but don't expect to ever need any revisions before 190000. `svnsync` can handle checking out each revision from 1-200000, but will likely be a multiple-day process, taking up 10's of GBs of space.  Is is possible to combine an svn checkout/export of revision 190000 as well as the set of changes for each revision from 190000-200000?

`svnsync` didn't seem to have any options to limit the set of revisions being pulled, and when I tried using the `-r 190000:200000` option with `git-svn`, it seemed to only do the second part, pulling the changes from each revision as a commit but not the state of the repository at revision 190000. I also tried creating a new `git` repo, then `svn export <remote_repo_URL>@190000`, followed by `git svn fetch -r 190000:200000 <remote_repo_url>`, but `git-svn` refused to work on a `git` repo it had not created.

**Bonus**: I don't foresee having to go back further revisions, but should the need unexpectedly arise, is there a way to also add earlier revisions (ie: revisions before 190000 in the given example)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about git but mercurial svn has a keyword `--startrev` so you could try:

`hg clone --startrev 190000 svn+`*url*

it is worth generating an authors list and supplying that with -A.

You can also clone a specific branch.

The results of `hg -v help clone`

> hg clone [OPTION]... SOURCE [DEST]
>
> make a copy of an existing repository
>
> ```
> Create a copy of an existing repository in a new directory.
>
> If no destination directory name is specified, it defaults to the basename
> of the source.
>
> The location of the source is added to the new repository's ".hg/hgrc"
> file, as the default to be used for future pulls.
>
> Only local paths and "ssh://" URLs are supported as destinations. For
> "ssh://" destinations, no working directory or ".hg/hgrc" will be created
> on the remote side.
>
> To pull only a subset of changesets, specify one or more revisions
> identifiers with -r/--rev or branches with -b/--branch. The resulting
> clone will contain only the specified changesets and their ancestors.
> These options (or 'clone src#rev dest') imply --pull, even for local
> source repositories. Note that specifying a tag will include the tagged
> changeset but not the changeset containing the tag.
>
> If the source repository has a bookmark called '@' set, that revision will
> be checked out in the new repository by default.
>
> To check out a particular version, use -u/--update, or -U/--noupdate to
> create a clone with no working directory.
>
> For efficiency, hardlinks are used for cloning whenever the source and
> destination are on the same filesystem (note this applies only to the
> repository data, not to the working directory). Some filesystems, such as
> AFS, implement hardlinking incorrectly, but do not report errors. In these
> cases, use the --pull option to avoid hardlinking.
>
> In some cases, you can clone repositories and the working directory using
> full hardlinks with
>
>   $ cp -al REPO REPOCLONE
>
> This is the fastest way to clone, but it is not always safe. The operation
> is not atomic (making sure REPO is not modified during the operation is up
> to you) and you have to make sure your editor breaks hardlinks (Emacs and
> most Linux Kernel tools do so). Also, this is not compatible with certain
> extensions that place their metadata under the .hg directory, such as mq.
>
> Mercurial will update the working directory to the first applicable
> revision from this list:
>
> a) null if -U or the source repository has no changesets
> b) if -u . and the source repository is local, the first parent of the
>    source repository's working directory
> c) the changeset specified with -u (if a branch name, this means the
>    latest head of that branch)
> d) the changeset specified with -r
> e) the tipmost head specified with -b
> f) the tipmost head specified with the url#branch source syntax
> g) the revision marked with the '@' bookmark, if present
> h) the tipmost head of the default branch
> i) tip
>
> Examples:
>
> - clone a remote repository to a new directory named hg/:
>
>     hg clone http://selenic.com/hg
>
> - create a lightweight local clone:
>
>     hg clone project/ project-feature/
>
> - clone from an absolute path on an ssh server (note double-slash):
>
>     hg clone ssh://user@server//home/projects/alpha/
>
> - do a high-speed clone over a LAN while checking out a specified version:
>
>     hg clone --uncompressed http://server/repo -u 1.5
>
> - create a repository without changesets after a particular revision:
>
>     hg clone -r 04e544 experimental/ good/
>
> - clone (and track) a particular named branch:
>
>     hg clone http://selenic.com/hg#stable
>
> See "hg help urls" for details on specifying URLs.
>
> Returns 0 on success.
>
> Subversion sources can be used for clone. See 'hg help hgsubversion' for
> more on the conversion process.
> ```
>
> options:
>
> -U --noupdate          the clone will include an empty working copy
>   (only a
>                           repository)  -u --updaterev REV     revision, tag or branch to check out  -r --rev REV [+]       include the
>   specified changeset  -b --branch BRANCH [+] clone only the specified
>   branch
>       --pull              use pull protocol to copy metadata
>       --uncompressed      use uncompressed transfer (fast over LAN)  -e --ssh CMD           specify ssh command to use
>       --remotecmd CMD     specify hg command to run on the remote side
>       --insecure          do not verify server certificate (ignoring web.cacerts
>                           config)
>       --stupid            use slower, but more compatible, protocol for
>                           Subversion  -T --tagpaths VALUE    list of paths to search for tags in Subversion
>                           repositories
>       --branchdir VALUE   path to search for branches in subversion repositories
>       --infix VALUE       path relative to trunk, branch an tag dirs to import  -A --authors VALUE     file mapping Subversion usernames to
>   Mercurial authors
>       --filemap VALUE     file containing rules for remapping Subversion
>                           repository paths
>       --layout VALUE      import standard layout or single directory? Can be
>                           standard, single, or auto. (default: auto)
>       --branchmap VALUE   file containing rules for branch conversion
>       --tagmap VALUE      file containing rules for renaming tags
>       --startrev VALUE    convert Subversion revisions starting at the one
>                           specified, either an integer revision or HEAD; HEAD
>                           causes only the latest revision to be pulled
>
> [+] marked option can be specified multiple times
>
> global options:
>
> -R --repository REPO   repository root directory or name of overlay
>   bundle
>                           file
>       --cwd DIR           change working directory  -y --noninteractive    do not prompt, automatically pick the first choice for
>                           all prompts  -q --quiet             suppress output  -v --verbose           enable additional output
>       --config CONFIG [+] set/override config option (use 'section.name=value')
>       --debug             enable debugging output
>       --debugger          start debugger
>       --encoding ENCODE   set the charset encoding (default: UTF-8)
>       --encodingmode MODE set the charset encoding mode (default: strict)
>       --traceback         always print a traceback on exception
>       --time              time how long the command takes
>       --profile           print command execution profile
>       --version           output version information and exit  -h --help              display help and exit
>       --hidden            consider hidden changesets
>       --color TYPE        when to colorize (boolean, always, auto, or never)
>                           (default: auto)
>
> [+] marked option can be specified multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`svnrdump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnrdump.html): for `svnrdump dump` it accept revisions (or revision's range in usual Subversion's format) and dump in this case only specified range